# Как выбор последний элемент

Tags: css, css3

Как выбрать последний элемент.
Но если стоит `class .none` тогда выбрать пред последний.

```css
.menuElement:last-child {
  color: red;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="menuElement">Element1</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element2</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element3</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element4</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element5</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element6</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element7</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element8</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element9</li>
  <li class="menuElement none">Element10</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

с помощью css это сделать нельзя. на :last-child нельзя наложить условие (это всегда последний элемент видимый или нет).

можно сделать при помощи селекторов jquery. файктически это означает, что при помощи javascript.

также можно сделать на ванильном javascript (кода будет чуть больше). переделал пример ниже под него.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.menuElement:not(.none)');
if (items.length > 0)
  items[items.length-1].className += ' last';
```

```css
.menuElement.last {
  color: red;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="menuElement">Element1</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element2</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element3</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element4</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element5</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element6</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element7</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element8</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element9</li>
  <li class="menuElement none">Element10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Алексей, пожалуйста можете написать на vanila JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

```css
li.menuElement:last-child {color: blue;} /* последний элемент */
li:not(.none).menuElement {color: red;} /* все элементы без класса .none */
/*----------------------------------------*/
li.menuElement:nth-last-child(2) /* вот так можно выбрать предпоследний элемент, но проверку на наличие класса у последнего li делать через js, но по сути первый вариант должен решить вашу проблему */
```

Comment: при помощи css сделать то, что просит Полосатый Тигр нельзя...

Comment: собственно это и написано в примере. но для большинства случаев достаточно того что я написал в примере. 2 первые строки

Answer (score 2):

1. Вы НЕ можете в css задать селектор для родительского или предшествующего элемента. Смиритесь или используйте яваскрипт.
2. Перестройте список чтобы он шел в обратном порядке. Потом обстильте его так ,чтобы визуально порядок был прямой. Тогда вы сможете подействовать на "предпоследний" элемент, не зная его номера (т.к. по DOM он второй):

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.menuElement:first-child,
.menuElement.none:first-child+.menuElement {
  color: red;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Последний элемент 'none':<br>

<ul>
  <li class="menuElement none">Element10</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element9</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element8</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element7</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element6</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element5</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element4</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element3</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element2</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element1</li>

</ul>

Последний элемент НЕ 'none':<br>
<ul>
  <li class="menuElement">Element10</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element9</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element8</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element7</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element6</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element5</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element4</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element3</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element2</li>
  <li class="menuElement">Element1</li>

</ul>
```